# Add image (cover art) to Opus (ogg) audio file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, file-metadata, ogg

## Question

I have 2 files:

- `audio.opus` (extension also possible: `.opus.ogg`),
- `cover.jpg`.

**How can I use `ffmpeg` to put `cover.jpg` as an embedded "cover" image into `audio.opus`?**

### Constraints

- I don't want to re-encode the audio (so unfortunately, `opusenc --picture` seems out of scope),
- I don't want to re-encode the image (jpeg), although that's not much of a problem,
- I don't want to transform the image into a video (!),
- I'd really prefer doing it with `ffmpeg` and not another tool,
- I don't want to hear about mp3.

### Expected result

Here is how it should look like when it's properly done:

```
$ opusinfo audio_with_cover.opus
Processing file "audio_with_cover.opus"...

New logical stream (#1, serial: 39a74bbb): type opus
Encoded with libopus 1.3.1
User comments section follows...
    ENCODER=opusenc from opus-tools 0.1.10
    METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE=3|image/jpeg||1280x720x24|<45952 bytes of image data>
    ENCODER_OPTIONS=--bitrate 56
Opus stream 1:
    Pre-skip: 312
    [...]
```

Or seen from `ffprobe`:

```
$ ffprobe audio_with_cover.opus 
[ogg @ 0x55675650ca80] 761 bytes of comment header remain
Input #0, ogg, from 'audio_with_cover.opus':
  Duration: 00:02:25.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 71 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : opusenc from opus-tools 0.1.10
      ENCODER_OPTIONS : --bitrate 56
  Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, 90k tbr, 90k tbn (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      comment         : Cover (front)
```

### Not possible?

If you know it is not possible, please let me know, I will open a feature request at `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Open a ticket at trac.ffmpeg.org and reference this pending patch: https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/project/ffmpeg/list/?series=7314

Comment: Thank you @Gyan, I [added to the already existing ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4448#comment:6) with a reference to the patch you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-metadata:s:a METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE=...` to add the image data manually, but the provided data has to follow the [Xiph Vorbis Comment structure.](https://xiph.org/flac/format.html#metadata_block_picture)

First, you have to create a matching header block (which fortunately can be reused when the image size etc. stays the same), and then concatenate it with the base64 encoded image data.

For more details, see https://superuser.com/a/1816195/1860118

Comment: Nice hint! Would you give an example of the commands needed to do this (if the starting file is, for example, `cover.jpg`)?